# Can I sue a company for testing Captcha when unsubscribing from email?

Tags: gdpr

With all the data protection stuff these days I was wondering if it is possible to sue a company for making a user pass a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) test when unsubscribing from email.

I don't know the law surrounding this issue but the user experience is horrendous:

I get an email that I don't want from a company I don't really care about into my personal inbox. They provide a link below, as legally mandated I believe, for me to be able to unsubscribe from their mailing list. I am directed to an external URL where most companies quickly confirm the saved preferences. Why should I need to pass a CAPTCHA when an email was clicked directly from my inbox? This is mostly hypothetical right now, but I am wondering if there are any laws (e.g., GDPR) that would make this actionable.

Comment: Even if there are GDPR-like laws covering this, it's far more likely that the company would be required to pay a fine to some government/regulatory body, and not you. For you to successfully sue them you'd probably have to show and quantify how you were 'damaged' by their actions...

Comment: Right. Could you also not argue they're making it artificially harder to unsubscribe from their emails?

Comment: Sure you could - but what actual harm have you suffered which you would be suing them to compensate you for? 30 seconds of your time and a minor annoyance is worth what ... $0.50 ... ?

Comment: You can provide a simple unsubscribe link, or you can make it too complicated and I will simply flag the message as spam. Then not only I, but also your other potential customers will stop seeing it. Your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [10 rules for getting email unsubscribes right](https://econsultancy.com/10-rules-for-getting-email-unsubscribes-right/) on Econsultancy, the GDPR says of unsubscribing (my emphasis):

> There is no specific rule about how companies should allow unsubscribing from email, but the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) does state that **removing consent should be as easy as giving it**. This means that if businesses try to make it difficult or confusing they may find themselves receiving complaints.

So, assuming they do not *otherwise* hinder unsubscribing in some of the ways described on that page, would having to pass a Captcha test stop unsubscribing being *as easy as* signing up?

Obviously, it can depend on exactly how you sign up. Some processes may have involved a Captcha test in the first place, or validating your email to activate an account: in such cases, it feels like a clear draw. Even if all that was involved to sign-up was to enter your email-address on a web-page, then passing a single Captcha test doesn't really sound like a significant difference.

Also, much as I hate "defending" companies that try to flood you with emails, there are some practical reasons for including something like a Captcha test. In your question you say "*when an email was clicked directly from my inbox*". However, they don't necessarily *know* it came directly from your inbox:

- Depending on the format of the link, it may be possible for a mischievous third-party to spoof requests to the unsubscribe page. A Captcha helps ensure a human actually did the clicking.
- Even if the format of the link is "encoded" in a way to make it "spoof-proof", it is known that *some* email clients might "pre-visit" links they find in emails (see, [How to stop e-mail clients from visiting links in e-mail automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43443947/2096401) on StackOverflow). One of the reasons for doing this, I believe, is to help protect users from dangerous links in "phishing" and similar emails. However, it can also mean that without *some* kind of secondary confirmation (e.g. Captcha), people could get unwittingly auto-unsubscribed by their email client.

Overall, I would say that a Captcha alone is *not* sufficient to hinder the unsubscribing process to the point you can hit them with things like GDPR, especially as there are some practical justifications for including one.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thank you.